# Acceder a una cookie creada con PHP vía jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, cookies

Tengo un proyecto creado con Laravel y necesito crear unas Cookies con php, hasta ahí todo bien, puedo acceder a ellas usando `Cookie::get()`. El problema es que estoy intentando acceder a ellas vía jQuery, pero `console.log( document.cookie.split(';') );` no me devuelve las cookies que he creado, sin embargo muestra todas las demás.

Será que no puedo acceder a cookies creadas con PHP vía jQuery ¿?

Answer (score 0):

para leer las coo

```js
Cookies.get('cookie');
```

debes usar esta libreria es muy util para el manejo de cookies y no pesa nada

> https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/tree/latest

Comment: Nop... no me funciona, y lo he probado en varios navegadores...